# Мультипроцессор пайтон Ошибка в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, selenium, python-3.6

```
import time
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import multiprocessing
import selenium
from multiprocessing import Process


password = "000000"
login ="login@"
serch ="googl"
main = "holo"
main():
      brawser.get("googl.com")
      textarea1 = brawser.find_element_by_xpath(serch)
      textarea1.send_keys(mail)
      submit = brawser.find_element_by_class_name('button')
      submit.click()
      time.sleep(3)
main2():
      brawser.get("vk.com")
      textarea1 = brawser.find_element_by_xpath(login)
      textarea1.send_keys(mail)
      textarea = brawser.find_element_by_class_name(password)
      textarea.send_keys(password)
      submit = brawser.find_element_by_class_name('main')
      submit.click()
      time.sleep(3)
try:
        while True :
            main()
            main2()
            time.sleep(3600)
            
        if __name__ == '__main__':
             p1 = Process(name='Worker 1', target=main)
             p2 = Process(name='Worker 2', target=main2)

        p1.start()
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception:", e)
```

П.С выдает ошибку только вот тут   if **name** == '**main**':
Что зделать чтоб запустилось 2 функции в мультипотоке?

Comment: Ваш код не компилируется. Сделайте нормальные определения функций с `def` и уберите этот странный `if` с присваиванием нуля. Соответственно, табуляция тоже лишняя дальше у всего кода.

Comment: А на `if` этот  ругается потому, что у него отступ такой же как у `try:`, а так нельзя, питон не понимает, где соответствующий `except:` тогда искать.

Comment: Короче, весь код сплошные ошибки синтаксиса. Как всё это исправлять не очень понятно, у вас там логика задваивается, ничего непонятно.

Comment: Убрал if .Эх, почему-то когда вставляю код табы и отступы изменяютца не как  не могу это исправить:( А что странный  if = 0? Просто работает у меня программа с 3-  if  это у меня типа свитч для выполнения кода по кусочкам.